# Project the sum of all fields in a document that match a regular expression, in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, I know I can specify the fields I want to return from documents that match my query using `{"fields":["fieldA", "fieldB", ..]}`.

But how do I return the sum of all fields that match a particular regular expression (as a new field)?

For example, if my documents look like this:

```
{"documentid":1,
 "documentStats":{
    "foo_1_1":1,
    "foo_2_1":5,
    "boo_1_1:3
 }
}
```

and I want the sum of all stats that match `_1_` per document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an artificial field called [`script_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-script-fields.html) that contains a small Groovy script, which will do the job for you.

So after your query, you can add a `script_fields` section like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        ...
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "sum" : {
            "script" : "_source.documentStats.findAll{ it.key =~ '_1_'}.collect{it.value}.sum()"
        }
    }
}
```

What the script does is simply to retrieve all the fields in `documentStats` whose name matches `_1_` and sums all their values, in this case, you'll get 4.

Make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in `elasticsearch.yml` and restart your ES node before trying this out.

Comment: THANK you so much!

Comment: One more question..
I managed to use script_fields and sort based on a script, for something simpler. If documentStats is an array "documentStats":[
    {"foo_1_1":1},
    {"foo_2_1":5},
    {"boo_1_1:3}
 ]
how would I modify the groovy script?

Comment: As this deviates a bit from the original requirement, I guess you should ask another question so as to keep this one clean for future readers.

Comment: Thank you Val, I have asked a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465248/proper-groovy-script-for-sum-of-fields-in-elasticsearch-documents