# Proper groovy script for sum of fields in Elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

This question is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448188/project-the-sum-of-all-fields-in-a-document-that-match-a-regular-expression-in/37451131?noredirect=1#comment62425713_37451131).

If my documents look like so:

```
{"documentid":1,
"documentStats":[ {"foo_1_1":1}, {"foo_2_1":5}, {"boo_1_1":3} ]
}
```

What would be the correct groovy script to be used in a script_field for returning the sum of all documentStats per document that match a particular pattern, (e.g., contain `_1_`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the referred question, there's a one-liner that does the same thing with your new structure:

```
{
    "query" : {
        ...
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "sum" : {
            "script" : "_source.documentStats.findAll{ it.keySet()[0] =~'_1_' }.collect{it.values()}.flatten().sum()"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ES, but in pure Groovy you would do:

```
document.documentStats.collectMany { Map entry ->
  // assumes each entry has a single key and a single int value
  def item = entry.entrySet()[0]
  item.key.contains('_1_') ? [item.value] : []
}.sum()
```

Hope this helps.